# Why was this answer deleted

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-answers, moderators

This answer was recently deleted:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178815/137265

I am not quite sure why. I like to welcome new users and dislike it when they get downvoted for no reason ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16347778/50552).)

On the other hand, people who chain ask embarrassingly bad questions should be told to shape up or move out.

Is negativity forbidden in and of itself?  If not, what's the reason the answer was deleted?

Comment: Did you accidentally paste the wrong link? What you posted is not an answer.

Comment: @Kyle - only 10K users can see deleted answers.  See random's answer for the text of the deleted answer.

Comment: Is it ironic that a post about a deleted answer, has in it a deleted answer?

Answer (score 20):

That was not an answer.

They asked why questions with a lot of upvotes and monkey-barrelled answers are being, or have been, closed.

You said they should work on their own question quality.

> Honestly, reading your questions, I'm not sure if the Stack Overflow community wants you to be part of it.
>
> Start working on writing better questions.

At best that's something you rephrase with a little more tact if they're asking why they're auto-blocked from asking questions.

Comment: To expand a little on random's comments, we have long had a content focused culture here. That is we ask people to vote the post, not the poster. The way it put that answer focuses on the person. Not good. Much better to have concentrated on their posts.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the deleted answer? I am missing some context here...

Comment: The question says "a bunch of **my** completely good, legitimate and constructive questions," (emphasis added.)  But his questions are neither.  A blunt statement can help make the problem visible.

Comment: @edit: wait, is that the full answer? *(also, as usual, love the edit comment :D)*